# Laravel 5 Eloquent 2 tables with pivot to json

Tags: json, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have 3 tables, naws/facility_naw(pivot table)/facilities.
If make a foreach and another foreach with facilities then it works fine.
Now i want the data to be accessable as api and i want to return all to a json.
So i made a new controller ApiController.

```
@foreach( $naws as $naw )
    @foreach( $naw->facilities )
        etc
        etc
    @end
@endforeach
```

How can i achieve that?

[image: Tables]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $result = [];

 foreach( $naws as $naw ):
 foreach( $naw->facilities ):
    $result[] = etc;
 endforeach;
endforeach

return $result;
```

Comment: You mean do this in the controller, make a new array and return as json?

Comment: @Bas Yes, just return the variable.

Comment: @Bas Glad to help :)